# Fourier transform not giving expected result

Tags: python, plot, fft

It is the case that a Fourier transform of a signal from time space to frequency space will have a peak corresponding to the frequency of the original signal. My problem is that when I try to plot the outcome of the Fourier transform using the numpy.fft.fft function and scaling 'appropriately' I get a peak corresponding to **twice** the frequency of the signal. Can anybody see why?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

A=2
f0=4
t=np.linspace(0,2,200)
phase=0

s=[]
for i in t:
    s.append(A*np.sin(2*np.pi*f0*i+phase))

N = int(len(s))
yf = np.fft.fft(s)[1:N//2]
xf = np.linspace(1, N//2-1, len(yf))
yf1=yf*np.conj(yf)/N

plt.plot(xf, yf1)
plt.xlim([0,15])
```

Comment: `plt.plot(s)` and count the cycles, you probably want 1 as range in `t=np.linspace(0,**1**,200)`

Comment: Yep I actually realised my error was that the output yf1 will not just be the amplitude of the frequencies in the frequency domain. Instead it will be (frequency amplitude)*(time period). So doing what you said would work as there would be a time period of 1 in t, as appose to 2 before.More generally putting f=f0/(t[-1]-t[0]) worked. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!